# For an ideal $\mathfrak{a}$, find an $x$ such that $\mathfrak{d}(x)=\mathfrak{a}^{-1}$

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field, $\mathfrak{a}$ a nonzero ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{K}$, and $\mathfrak{d}$ the different. If $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ is a PID, then one can find an $x$ such that $\mathfrak{d}(x)=\mathfrak{a}^{-1}$.

Is it possible to do this for any $K$ (in which the different may also not be principal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since the existence of $x$ implies that $\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{d}$ is a principal ideal.

If you want a counterexample, take any number field $K$ where the different ideal is not principal and $\mathfrak{a}=\mathcal{O}_K$.

Comment: I see: is it possible to solve the weaker equation $\mathfrak{d}(y)=\mathfrak{b}\mathfrak{a}^{-1}$ for $y$, given $\mathfrak{a}$ (where $(\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b})=1)$)?

Comment: No. Same counterexample: take your ideals to be the ring of integers of $K$...Or take $\mathfrak{b}=\mathfrak{d}$ and $\mathfrak{a}$ to be non principal and coprime to $\mathfrak{d}$ .

Comment: Sorry : I wasn't very clear: $\mathfrak{a}$ is given but $\mathfrak{b}$ is not. How about that?